# c# winforms dynamically create controls based on fields with attributes (Attributes key word)

Tags: c#, attributes, controls

I have a class with fields;

```
bool field1;
bool field2;
bool field3;
...
bool field44;
bool field45;
...
```

I would like to dynamically populate a form with fields, but only specific fields.
Instead of using "if" to parse the fields by name,
Is it possible to set an attribute on those fields I wish to include in my UC, and display only those.

```
[UC]//will be later on used to create a check box
bool field1;
[NOT_UC] //will be ignored
bool field2;
[UC]//will be later on used to create a check box
bool field3;
```

is there any other, more elegant design pattern that could be implemented for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind.
I figured it out.
first I created a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class UCAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public UCAttribute()
    { }
}
```

and set the [UC] attribute to desired fields

```
[UC]
bool field1;
```

later in UC:

```
    foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        object[] attribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        if (attribute.Length >= 1)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1} ", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item));
    }
```